# View ratio of answered/unanswered questions for each tag

Tags: feature-request, tags, statistics

It could be interesting to know the overall answered/unanswered ratio for each tag.  With that information it could be easy to see what are the domains most known by their users and the ones that are less known.

Could a way to view this ratio be implemented?  Possibly shown in the main Tags page?

Comment: Well maybe it is not a good idea for meta-stackoverflow: we could then know the ratio for the "bug" and "feature-request" tag. Ha!

Answer (score 3):

This would be cool.  Maybe there could be a red/yellow/green coding for different percentage thresholds on the main tags page and when you hover over the tag it displays the actual ratio.

On the flip-side, though, it would take some computing time to calculate the ratios.

Comment: I would expect it to be done maybe once a day and cached.  Which, of course, means it's not a trivial feature to implement.

Comment: @Polly: Yeah, I was thinking along the same lines there.

Answer (score 2):

It would also point out new languages vs well-established languages.  I'd be very interested in seeing an infographic with this and perhaps the top 100 tags...

Comment: This could be done using the data dump, but having it on the website in near-real-time would be fantabulous.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like a job for Data Dump Analysis!!! Maybe we should ask [this guy](http://broadcast.oreilly.com/2009/11/visualizing-stackoverflows-dat.html) to do it for us.